# How to fix not working calculation in dataframe pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hello everyone i have a problem in calculation a data frame in python. i have an equation name is TOC/Total_organic. below is the picture of my equation, code to make new colomns in my data frame, and the result [code and result from running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cld4s.png)

```
def total_organic (resis_log, dens_log, base_resislog, base_denslog, LOM):
delta_log = math.log10((resis_log/base_resislog)) - 2.5*(dens_log - base_denslog)
a = 0.297 - (0.1688*LOM)
TOC = delta_log * (10**a)
return round(TOC,2)

df_2['TOC'] = total_organic(df_2['AT90'], df_2['RHOM'], 0.5, 2.7, 14.2)ode here
```

Comment: Show code and full error message as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link. Indent the code properly.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! @MichaelButscher is referring to the guidance on [ask], which gives tips on [formatting](/help/formatting) and how to produce a [mre]. These are really important to check out when asking a question to ensure you'll get the best quality help. As your question currently stands, it's hard for us to know how to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `math.log10` cannot handle neither pandas dataframes nor ndarrays. You can use `np.log10` instead.

```py
import numpy as np


delta_log = np.log10((resis_log/base_resislog)) - 2.5*(dens_log - base_denslog)
```